# Get notified on new App Reviews?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

Does anyone know of a solution (app or site) that will automatically notify me anytime I get a review on one of my iOS apps?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apple provides an **RSS** you can subscribe to. You can find it by doing the following:

1. Go to **[iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com)** and log in
2. Go to **Manage your Apps** and select the App you're interested in
3. Under **Links**, in the **App Information** section, you'll find the **Customer Reviews**
4. Opening it will display all of the customer reviews, filtered by country.
5. Alongside the *combo box* to choose between the different countries you've already got reviews in, you'll find the RSS button.

**Note**: The countries combo box and the RSS button **will only be displayed** if there are reviews already.

[image]

[image]

The RSS URL looks like this:

`feed:https://itunes.apple.com/COUNTRY-OF-THE-REVIEW/rss/customerreviews/id=APP-ID/sortBy=mostRecent/xml?l=LANGUAGE-YOU-WANT-IT-TO-BE-DISPLAYED-IN`

Comment: I don’t think rss is available anymore? Can’t see a link?

Comment: It seems to be removed from the UI, but the URL format still works. This is the URL for the Twitter app in the US: https://itunes.apple.com/US/rss/customerreviews/id=333903271/sortby=mostrecent/xml

Answer (score 9):

I'm an iOS developer as well and I faced the same problem of wanting to be notified anytime a customer left a review for my apps on the App Store.

If your team uses Slack, check out https://appreviewbot.com/

Similarly if your team uses Microsoft Teams, check out https://appreviewbot.com/microsoft-teams/

Full disclosure: I created AppReviewBot and thought it might be useful for other indie developers like myself!

Comment: @freezegun Thanks for creating this app. I'm evaluating it for purposes of suggesting my company purchase it. I don't want to setup a subscription on their behalf, but I'd be happy to paypal/venmo/or non-subscription stripe you a few months worth of subscription for the evaluation if that's an option =)

Comment: @StanKurdziel Thanks so much for trying it out. Your support would be awesome! Shoot me a message through the website's contact form, I'm eager to get your feedback!

Comment: Thanks for this extension. What is the source of data behind this? Do you pull the reviews via RSS?

Comment: @user1615898 Yes I do use the RSS feeds. I frequently poll the feeds for all 155 supported App Store countries so that I can forward the reviews to Slack as soon as they occur!

Comment: Nice. Do you think there's a single feed for all countries review? In Itunes Connect there's a way to view All Countries review in the UI.

Comment: @user1615898 As far as I know there is not a single public RSS feed available but I really wish there were :P

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer an email to RSS you can check out Appbot.co. I am in no way affiliated with them but have found it useful.

I get a daily email that has a summary and then each of the reviews grouped by store.

I also get a weekly email that shows all the apps I've signed up for in one email with a summary of how they are doing week over week in terms of number of reviews and stars per review.

Comment: I would add that if you want a feed for apps from multiple platforms (like App Store + Google Play + Windows), to use a review manager like Review Command - https://reviewcommand.co

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to pay to get Slack notifications for new iOS App Store reviews, you could easily get that configured in Zapier. You get up to 5 free zaps.

Here is a [blog post](https://medium.com/@alibadereddin/ios-app-store-reviews-email-or-slack-notifications-7cc6318a6740) I wrote describing the steps.

You could also download the free App Store Connect app built by Apple and get notifications via the app.

Comment: Please quote and include the steps from your blog in the answer, to make it self contained, without needing to visit external sites, for two reasons: (1) In case of [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot), and; (2) This could be considered self-promotion of your web site. Please take the [tour] to get a better understanding of how Stack Exchange works.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/324012)